# how to remove a row based on elementwise situation?

Tags: r

I have a data frame like below

```
V1        V2       V3        V4      V5
ATP1A2  ATP1A1  220948_s_at LARS2   204016_at
CAPRIN1 ATP1A2              LARS2   
ATP1A1  ATP1A2  203296_s_at MTHFD1  202309_at
CBX3    ATP1B1  201243_s_at PRKCSH  200707_at
AUP1    ATP1B1              PRKCSH  214080_x_at
LARS2   AUP1    220525_s_at PRKCSH  
MTHFD1  AUP1                VDAC2   211662_s_at
VDAC2   B3GNT3  204856_at   VDAC2   
PRKCSH  B3GNT3          
ATP1B1  CAPRIN1 200722_s_at     
B3GNT3  CAPRIN1 200723_s_at     
        CAPRIN1         
        CBX3    200037_s_at
```

I want to remove those element from V2 that V3 is empty or from V4 that V5 is empty for example in V3, the second element is empty, so both the second element of V3 and V2 should be removed. how the output will looks like is seen below.

```
     V1        V2       V3         V4      V5
    ATP1A2  ATP1A1   220948_s_at   LARS2   204016_at
    CAPRIN1 ATP1A2   203296_s_at   MTHFD1  202309_at                  
    ATP1A1  ATP1B1   201243_s_at   PRKCSH  200707_at
    CBX3    AUP1     220525_s_at   PRKCSH  214080_x_at
    AUP1    B3GNT3   204856_at     VDAC2   211662_s_at
    LARS2   CAPRIN1  200722_s_at   
    MTHFD1  CAPRIN1  200723_s_at   
    VDAC2   CBX3     200037_s_at  
    PRKCSH          
    ATP1B1     
    B3GNT3
```

I can detect how to find those empty string in each column but the problem is how to remove two columns rows based on that and do it for all data frame

```
# to find the empty elements 
Rcolumn3 <-which(df$V3=="")
Rcolumn5 <-which(df$V5=="") 

df<- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(3L, 7L, 2L, 8L, 5L, 9L, 10L, 
12L, 11L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "ATP1A1", "ATP1A2", 
"ATP1B1", "AUP1", "B3GNT3", "CAPRIN1", "CBX3", "LARS2", "MTHFD1", 
"PRKCSH", "VDAC2"), class = "factor"), V2 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L), .Label = c("ATP1A1", 
"ATP1A2", "ATP1B1", "AUP1", "B3GNT3", "CAPRIN1", "CBX3"), class = "factor"), 
    V3 = structure(c(9L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 
    4L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("", "200037_s_at", "200722_s_at", 
    "200723_s_at", "201243_s_at", "203296_s_at", "204856_at", 
    "220525_s_at", "220948_s_at"), class = "factor"), V4 = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
    "LARS2", "MTHFD1", "PRKCSH", "VDAC2"), class = "factor"), 
    V5 = structure(c(4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "200707_at", "202309_at", "204016_at", 
    "211662_s_at", "214080_x_at"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3", "V4", "V5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))
```

you can get the data by

Comment: You could try `df[,2:3] <- rbind(df[-Rcolumn3,2:3], data.frame(V2=rep('', length(Rcolumn3)), V3=rep('', length(Rcolumn3))); df[,4:5] <- rbind(df[-Rcolumn5,4:5], data.frame(V4=rep('', length(Rcolumn5)), V5=rep('', length(Rcolumn5)))); df[rowSums(df!='')!=0,]`

Comment: @akrun thanks but if i have like 1000 columns which then i want to do it alternatively, it is not convenience to do it like this, is it not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a way:

```
#convert to character
df[] <- lapply(df, as.character)

#convert the equivalent V2 or V4 columns' rows into '' 
a <- which(df$V3=='')
b <- which(df$V5=='')

df$V2[a] <- ''
df$V4[b] <- ''
```

At this point I ve written a function that pushes the blanks to the end/bottom of a vector/column:

```
push_up <- function(vec){
   c(vec[-which(vec=='')], vec[which(vec=='')])
}
```

and apply that to the df:

```
df[] <- lapply(df, push_up)
```

Output:

```
> df
        V1      V2          V3     V4          V5
1   ATP1A2  ATP1A1 220948_s_at  LARS2   204016_at
2  CAPRIN1  ATP1A2 203296_s_at MTHFD1   202309_at
3   ATP1A1  ATP1B1 201243_s_at PRKCSH   200707_at
4     CBX3    AUP1 220525_s_at PRKCSH 214080_x_at
5     AUP1  B3GNT3   204856_at  VDAC2 211662_s_at
6    LARS2 CAPRIN1 200722_s_at                   
7   MTHFD1 CAPRIN1 200723_s_at                   
8    VDAC2    CBX3 200037_s_at                   
9   PRKCSH                                       
10  ATP1B1                                       
11  B3GNT3                                       
12                                               
13
```

Or `df[df$V1 != '',]` to remove rows 12,13

Answer (score 2):

We could try `set` from `data.table` as there are many columns (created 'df1' with a couple more columns).  The basic approach is similar to @Lyzander's, i.e. changing the elements that are not `''` in alternating columns to `''` based on the `''` values in the other column and then "push" the `''` elements to the end of each column.  (Assumption is that the modification starts for alternating columns from the 2nd column).

```
library(data.table)
df1 <- cbind(df, setNames(df[-1], paste0('V',6:9)))
```

Changed the column class from  `factor` to `character` as it will be easier for changing the values.

```
df1[] <- lapply(df1, as.character)
```

Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table'

```
setDT(df1)
```

Create a numeric index for the alternating column

```
j1 <- as.integer(seq(3, ncol(df1), by=2))
```

Use `set` to replace the elements in the 'j-1th' column based on the presence of `''` in the 'jth' column, `order` the 'jth' and 'j-1th' columns based on the presence of `''` (2nd and 3rd `set` lines).  I am not sure if this is the most efficient though (considering three lines of `set`), but `set` in general is very efficient as the overhead of `[.data.table` is avoided

```
for(j in j1){
  set(df1, i=which(df1[[j]]==''), j=j-1L, value='')
  set(df1, i=NULL, j=j, value= df1[[j]][order(df1[[j]]=='')])
  set(df1, i=NULL, j=j-1L, value= df1[[j-1L]][order(df1[[j-1L]]=='')])
}
```

Remove the `''` elements at the end of `V1` column to get the expected result.

```
df1[V1!='']
#        V1      V2          V3     V4          V5      V6          V7     V8
#1:  ATP1A2  ATP1A1 220948_s_at  LARS2   204016_at  ATP1A1 220948_s_at  LARS2
#2: CAPRIN1  ATP1A2 203296_s_at MTHFD1   202309_at  ATP1A2 203296_s_at MTHFD1
#3:  ATP1A1  ATP1B1 201243_s_at PRKCSH   200707_at  ATP1B1 201243_s_at PRKCSH
#4:    CBX3    AUP1 220525_s_at PRKCSH 214080_x_at    AUP1 220525_s_at PRKCSH
#5:    AUP1  B3GNT3   204856_at  VDAC2 211662_s_at  B3GNT3   204856_at  VDAC2
#6:   LARS2 CAPRIN1 200722_s_at                    CAPRIN1 200722_s_at       
#7:  MTHFD1 CAPRIN1 200723_s_at                    CAPRIN1 200723_s_at       
#8:   VDAC2    CBX3 200037_s_at                       CBX3 200037_s_at       
#9:  PRKCSH                                                                  
#10:  ATP1B1                                                                  
#11:  B3GNT3                                                                  
#            V9
#1:   204016_at
#2:   202309_at
#3:   200707_at
#4: 214080_x_at
#5: 211662_s_at
#6:            
#7:            
#8:            
#9:            
#10:            
#11:
```

Comment: @Nemo Thanks for your generous comments.